# How should I compress my network traffic? How to make my connection 'faster'?

Tags: networking, compression

I have a slow ADSL currently, which could really benefit from some compression. I've also got servers in the country, with a very low ping (0, 1ms to the my ISP).

**Which software, 'solution' should I use, to compress traffic?**

So far I only met two candidates: **SSH** (using "Compression", but I just can't verify if my browser really gets compressed data), and if I open a **VPN connection** (PPTP I guess), that also displays a "compression x%".

Comment: (For example: When I open up an ssh connection to my server, with dynamic port forward, enabled compression in PuTTY (compression is enabled in sshd, also, the server (Debian) openSSH comes with comp.) How do I know if it works? Is there a way to check this?)

Comment: Is your network traffic comperssible at all? E.g., most graphic, music and video files are already compressed, and cannot be compressed further. So, if your traffic is 99% already compressed, you stand to benefit very little from further compression. Moreover, given the additional latency, your browsing speed can actually be *slower* if you enable compression.

Comment: Most of the pages I browse (news site, etc) got a lot of text. I would like to compress those.

Comment: Some sites compress their text as well (transparently): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [ziproxy](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/) if can install software on the servers. Info from the site: "Basically, it squeezes images by converting them to lower quality JPEGs or JPEG 2000 and compresses (gzip) HTML and other text-like data. It also provides other features such as: HTML/JS/CSS optimization, preemptive hostname resolution, transparent proxying, IP ToS marking (QoS), Ad-Blocker, detailed logging and more."

Comment: Another alternative is: RabbIT v4 proxy. (Java based, same principle.)